# How to checkout a spezific Changeset in a Jenkins Pipeline build using using the buildin cm command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, plasticscm

I'm currently having a hard time figuring out how to check out a specific changeset using the build in cm command in a Jenkins Pipeline build. It seems that the changeset = 1234 parameter is ignored.
I tried the statement:
cm repository: item['Repo'], changeset: Stable_CS, server: item['server'], useUpdate: false, workspaceName: item['Repo']

Stable_CS is a variable that is filled with another cm command using the bat pipeline statement. It contains a string like 1234

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Plastic SCM plugin for Jenkins doesn't currently support checking out specific changesets, neither in freestyle projects nor pipelines. It can only target branches, as seen in the [Plugin wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PlasticSCM+Plugin).